# is it possible to increase the timeout of loading source map in google chrome dev tools

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, source-maps

I am using react to write a simple web application, now the google chrome devtools show warning that:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://ai.example.top/static/js/main.5fabf97b.js.map: Load canceled due to load timeout
```

I need the source map to debbugging my source code for some online pay logic, it it possible to increase the timeout of download process? or any other way to solve this problem?